# Unable to Run RabbitMq using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabbitmq

I am struggling to run the RabbitMq on rails. I am running this [sample](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-cloudfoundry-samples/tree/master/rails) on my local box, I was trying to tweak since I dont want to use CloudFoundry. I am aware of it. I am getting lot of errors like undefined method nameless exchange,undefined method publish. How do I tweak it in such a way so that I can run on my local box and deploy the same thing in any other platform other then cloudfoundry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [IronMQ](http://iron.io) by Iron.io. There's a large free offering that you can get up and running quickly with queuing. Also any of the platforms will have IronMQ as an addon option.